# how to set nowrap to a checkbox jquery control?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox

In jquery mobile the checkbox has a label caption and if the text is long, jqm  wrap it in multiline, I need to do like the second checkbox without space. eg.

```
<label style="white-space: nowrap;">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/evilripper/4rWMe/1/  :)

I tryed to set nowrap in the style of the label but doesn't works.

Comment: <LABEL style="white-space: nowrap;">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put text in a span:

```
<label>
    <input name="checkbox-0" type="checkbox" />
    <span style="white-space: nowrap;">Very long text with space Very long text with space Very long text with
     space</span>
 </label>
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/4rWMe/2/